# PGN viewer / replayer for Atomic Chess

Tags: pgn, atomic-chess

I'm looking for a PGN viewer that works with the Atomic chess variant, in that captures removes adjacent pieces. However, PGN viewers I've found so far have little to no support for chess variants, less to Atomic chess specifically. It doesn't matter if it works online as a web service or a separate program; what options are there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Winboard/XBoard should do the job.

http://www.tim-mann.org/xboard.html

Comment: You might want to use this link instead, as your page links there anyway: http://www.gnu.org/software/xboard/

Comment: linked to original developer for posterity and respect.

Comment: Okay, I see -- I didn't know he was the original developer.